# Best way to generate million tcp connection

Tags: sockets, tcp, connection

I  need to find a best way to generate a million tcp connections. (More is good,less is bad). As quickly as possible machinely :D

Why do I need this ? I am testing a nat, and I want to load it with as many entries as possible.

My current method is to generate a subnet on a dummy eth and serially connect from that dummy to actual eth to lan to nat to host.

```
subnetnicfake----routeToRealEth----RealEth---cable---lan----nat---host.   
|<-------------on my machine-------------------->|
```

Comment: A million *simultaneous* connections?

Comment: have you tried the [`iperf`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/) tool?

Comment: i dont know how iperf would help in this case ?

Comment: @nikhilelite have you tried EchoServerTest http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2005/11/windows-tcpip-server-performance.html ?

Comment: i was able to get upto 600k if I remember correctly. I had 2 laptops to do this.  The trick was to reduce the buffer size, cwnd size and wscale etc for the TCP proto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for many days, I found the problem. Apparently this problem is well thought over, and it should be ,since its so very basic. The problem was, I didnt know what this problem should be called . Among know-ers, it apparently called as c10k problem. What I wanted is c1m problem. However there seems to be some effort done to get C500k . or Concurrent 500k connections.

http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html             AND
          http://urbanairship.com/blog/2010/09/29/linux-kernel-tuning-for-c500k/

@deadalnix.

Read above links ,and enlighten yourself.

Comment: From link above : « The misconception begins with the premise that there are only so many ephemeral ports per IP. The truth is that the limit is based on the IP pair, or said another way, the client and server IPs together. A single client IP can connect to a server IP 64,000 times and so can another client IP.» Which the case here because of the NAT.

Answer (score 4):

One million simultaneous TCP sessions might be difficult: If you rely on standard `connect(2)` sockets API to create the functions, you're going to use a *lot* of physical memory: each session will require a `struct inet_sock`, which includes a `struct sock`, which includes a `struct sock_common`.

I quickly guessed at sizes: `struct sock_common` requires at roughly 58 bytes. `struct sock` requires roughly 278 bytes. `struct inet_sock` requires roughly 70 bytes.

That's 387 megabytes of data *before you have receive and send buffers*. (See `tcp_mem`, `tcp_rmem`, `tcp_wmem` in `tcp(7)` for some information.)

If you choose to go this route, I'd suggest setting the per-socket memory controls as low as they go. I wouldn't be surprised if 4096 is the lowest you can set it. (`SK_MEM_QUANTUM` is `PAGE_SIZE`, stored into `sysctl_tcp_rmem[0]` and `sysctl_tcp_wmem[0]`.)

That's another eight gigabytes of memory -- four for receive buffers, four for send buffers.

And that's in addition to what the system requires for your programs to open one million file descriptors. (See `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` in `proc(5)`.)

All of this memory is *not swappable* -- the kernel pins its memory -- so you're really only approaching this problem on a 64-bit machine with at least eight gigabytes of memory. Probably 10-12 would do better.

One approach taken by the [Paketto Keiretsu tools](http://dankaminsky.com/) is to open a raw connection, perform all the TCP three-way handshakes using a single raw socket, and try to compute whatever is needed, rather than store it, to handle much larger amounts of data than usual. Try to store as little as possible for each connection, and don't use naive lists or trees of structures.

The Paketto Keiretsu tools were last updated around 2003, so they still might not scale into the million range well, but they would definitely be my starting point if this were my problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/)? You could prepare - or capture - one or more PCAP network capture files with the traffic that you need, and have one or more instances of tcpreplay replay them to stress-test your firewall/NAT.

Answer (score -4):

as long as you have 65536 port available in TCP, this is impossible to achive unless you have an army of servers to connect to.

So, then, what is the best way ? Just open as many connection as you can on servers and see what happens.

Comment: Those ports are per ip. and I am saying I have a fake subnet of those. so per IP you get 65536 max(though its severely limited by file descriptor limit and other params). But My point is to increase speed , I dont have time to sit around for 1/2 an hour to get those connections working. Anyone have any good idea to multiply speed ?

Comment: @deadalnix This is not correct. He doesn't need an army of servers. He is constrained in the number of outbound connections per client, but incoming connections per server are not constrained by the port space. They use the same port number as the port being listened to.

Comment: The server will create a socket per connection. So, the limited factor is the size of file descriptor table.

Comment: Yes, the server can handle one socket per connexion. But the client cannot open an infinite number of socket on the server. Both of the client and the server are nneded to achieve a connection. And the server cannot be behind the NAT. So you must either have a lot of servers to connect to, either a lot of client to connect to the server. Please guy, understand basics of networking before actually claiming me wrong.

Comment: Don't forget, you've got 64*1024 source ports and 64*1024 destination ports for a total of 64*64*1024*1024 == four _billion_ possible connections between two hosts with a single IP address each.

Comment: Destination port is fixed. The server open a socket waiting for client to connect to that socket. If you have severals ports opens on the server (hardware) to connect to, then you are running several servers (software) on that machine.

Comment: I dont know how your calculating, in my opinion, the server port is fixed, so for a pair of IP, ie. cliIP1<-->ServIP:port , the limit is 65536.(or that range defined in /proc/../ipv4 files). So, for 1 pair of ips, I have max 64k. But now I can alias another ip on the same machine(the subnet i referred to is this), so I have one machine with 2 ips, and 65k+65k range. so on and so forth.

Comment: @deadalnix My server is behind nat and it works, because I have implemented an ALG for dns requests, that installs appropriate temp entries in nat. So yes I know what I am talking about very much- because I have it working, and it works fine. So you please do not comment any arbit stuff.

Comment: Feel free to write your server to `bind(2)`, `listen(2)` and `accept(2)` on all 64k ports. Perhaps some NAT systems will fall apart when stressed this far (see my memory calculations elsewhere), but that's part of what testing the NAT system is all about. :)

Comment: @deadalnix I think you do not have basic understanding of how IP protocol works. The limit of 65536 is for 1 Ip, I HAVE SUBNET OF SUCH 1 IPS. WHICH MEANS I CAN GENERATE 65536 * NUMBER OF IPS I HAVE connections, which connect to 1 SERVER IP: PORT.    The limitation is file descriptors and other parameters like ephemeral port range etc. There is no question of liking, you didn't even know servers can be behind nat.

Comment: No, servers cannot be behind NAT unless you have a port redirection, which means that you disable the NAT for that particular server. And, you won't have a whole subnet as long as the server see the NAT address, and is not aware of the subnet within. Your NAT will reject connection from your subnet when that limit is reached. I have a master degree in networking, cisco certigfication, I work on SaaS for years and you are asking the question here. But sure, explain me ;)

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2694.txt . You are very confused person,it is better that you again everything again for your sake. I am not doing port nat or napt. Its simple destination nat. The source address is not of NAT its of whatever subnet's ip. the destination is changed to internal when packet travels inside and the source is changed to external when packet travels to outside.

Comment: Ho god please. The NAT changes the address in the packet as you said. In result, server only see NAT's address, and is not aware of subnet address. NAT's address has 65536 ports, so, whatever how many adress you have on your subnet, on a single server, your whole subnet will only be able to open 65536 connection to that server. You NAT device will reject connection after that limit, and if it doesn't, it is bugguy.